# How to take value of a LINQ query in a model List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I can take value of this query in a variable but when I am trying to take value of this query in the "artistList " it shows error :[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvE2R.jpg)

This is the model :

```
public partial class tblArtist
    {
        public tblArtist()
        {
            this.tblArtistCategoryMappings = new HashSet<tblArtistCategoryMapping>();
            this.tblArtistGroupMembers = new HashSet<tblArtistGroupMember>();
            this.tblArtistPortfolios = new HashSet<tblArtistPortfolio>();
            this.tblArtistRatings = new HashSet<tblArtistRating>();
            this.tblArtistOverviews = new HashSet<tblArtistOverview>();
            this.tblArtistSchedules = new HashSet<tblArtistSchedule>();
        }

        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string ArtistName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Pin { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsGroup { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsFeatured { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> AddedOn { get; set; }
        public string AboutMe { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> MinmumRates { get; set; }
        public string FB_FanLink { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> FK_UserId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsApproved { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tblArtistCategoryMapping> tblArtistCategoryMappings { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblArtistGroupMember> tblArtistGroupMembers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblArtistPortfolio> tblArtistPortfolios { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblArtistRating> tblArtistRatings { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblArtistOverview> tblArtistOverviews { get; set; }
        public virtual tblUser tblUser { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblArtistSchedule> tblArtistSchedules { get; set; }
    }
```

In Controller page I take a list like :

```
List<tblArtist> artistList = new List<tblArtist>();
```

This is the query :

```
artistList = (from ta in context.tblArtists
                                    join tm in context.tblArtistCategoryMappings on ta.ArtistId equals tm.FK_ArtistId
                                    join tc in context.tblArtistCategories on tm.FK_CategoryId equals tc.ArtistCategoryId
                                    join tct in context.tblArtistCategoryTypes on tc.FK_ArtistCategoryTypeId equals tct.ArtistCategoryTypeId
                                    where tct.ArtistCategoryTypeId == TypesId && ta.IsFeatured == true
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        ta.AboutMe,
                                        ta.AddedOn,
                                        ta.Address,
                                        ta.ArtistId,
                                        ta.ArtistName,
                                        ta.City,
                                        ta.Country,
                                        ta.DateOfBirth,
                                        ta.Email,
                                        ta.FB_FanLink,
                                        ta.FK_UserId,
                                        ta.HouseNumber,
                                        ta.IsActive,
                                        ta.IsApproved,
                                        ta.IsFeatured,
                                        ta.IsGroup,
                                        ta.MinmumRates,
                                        ta.Mobile,
                                        ta.Phone,
                                        ta.Pin,
                                        ta.Sex,
                                        ta.State,
                                        ta.Website
                                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: You want to return list of tblArtist but you create an anonymous type in select clause. Just change it into select new tblArtist { ArtistId = ta.ArtistId, ... }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want records of only "tblArtists" table, then you can write like this;

```
artistList = (from ta in context.tblArtists
                                    join tm in context.tblArtistCategoryMappings on ta.ArtistId equals tm.FK_ArtistId
                                    join tc in context.tblArtistCategories on tm.FK_CategoryId equals tc.ArtistCategoryId
                                    join tct in context.tblArtistCategoryTypes on tc.FK_ArtistCategoryTypeId equals tct.ArtistCategoryTypeId
                                    where tct.ArtistCategoryTypeId == TypesId && ta.IsFeatured == true
                                    select ta).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you @Kinjal. It works properly but how can I add GROUP BY statement in this query?

Thank you

Comment: @SouravKuila That's a new question. For now, you have an answer.

Comment: If it is worked then plz give me vote on it. or put currect sign please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq this will help you. This is a reference for GroupBy.

Answer (score 0):

You select an anonymous type with this:

```
select new
    {
        ta.AboutMe,
        ta.AddedOn,
        // ..
    }
```

Linq cannot convert that anonymous type implicitly to `tblArtist` which it expects in the list of `List<tblArtist>`.

Instead of creating a new anonymous type, just create the `tblArtist`:

```
select new tblArtist
    {
        AboutMe = ta.AboutMe,
        AddedOn = ta.AddedOn,
        // ..
    }
```

**EDIT**

Or even better, I suspect that your `context.tblArtists` already is a collection of the type `tblArtist`, so you can just change the `select new` to `select ta` , then the result already is of the type you need.

Comment: Thanx for your reply @devqon. But I need to take value in this list "artistList " because In .cshtml page it is used. Can you tell me any other way or any other type of query?

Thank you

Comment: With my answer, you can just leave the rest as is. Just do the `.ToList()` and it works